# ResourceBundle getLocale().getDisplayLanguage() returns empty String

Tags: java, string, locale, resourcebundle

I am trying to internationalize my application, and I started practising with the `ResourceBundle` and `Locale`s with a simple function that creates a `ResourceBundle rb` with the default `Locale` of the machine and after it prints the language:

```
private void loadView() {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("languages_"+Locale.getDefault());
    System.out.println("Language: "+rb.getLocale().getDisplayLanguage());
}
```

I have different resource bundle properties files starting with *languages_*:
[Properties files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6KfP.png)

When I call the function *loadView* it does not print the language. It prints nothing.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should either don't specify locale at all to allow Java to resolve the current one

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("languages");
```

or use the `Locale` parameter instead of string concatenation

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("languages", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: This is what I have in my function, and it does not work

Comment: @Padro What is `Locale.getDefault()` returning?

Comment: _es_ES (I'm from Spain)

Comment: Oh! now it's working. Thank you. It was a  mistake. The second option that you say works!